# Can not login in iTune store for sandbox testing

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

As per the apple guide line we have create users in itune connect as per screen shot for sandbox testing to test in app purchase but when we have try to login. we got the below error "**iTune account creation not allowed**". Please check both the screenshot. [image]
[image]

Comment: I have faced this issue in past few months ago, dont login to any account. Try by going to IAP flow in your app , it will ask to create new apple id or login with existing apple id, here login with account which you created for sandbox testing, it will work.